# I can't change a property in a constructor function

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, prototype

I'm a newbie with JavaScript and I'm facing a problem with constructor functions, my problem is that I can't overwrite an old function's property with a new one!

Below is my code:

```js
function myFun() {
  this.anotherFun = function() {
    return true;
  }
}

var myVar = new myFun();

console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // returns 'true' as expected; 

myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function() {
  return false;
}

console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // is returns 'true' why not 'false'?
```

Comment: `myFun.prototype.anotherFun=` > `myFun.anotherFun=`

Comment: You have two functions, an own property and a prototype property. Own properties as dandavis points out are looked up first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when the same property appears multiple times in the prototypical chain, it makes sense to use the closest one.

Your instance has an own property, so you won't be able to override it by adding an inherited one.

You might have not wanted to add `myFun` as an own property

```js
function myFun(){}
myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true};
var myVar = new myFun();
console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // true
myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return false};
console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // false
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for me!, but why don't we write function myFun(){this.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true};} instead of function myFun(){}
myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true};

Comment: @M.Taki_Eddine Because there is no reason to run that code each time you create an instance. So it should be outside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do will not work with your code as own properties will always be looked up before prototype properties, so the change your are making to the prototype property will have no visible effect. In order for this to work, you can change your code to always use prototype properties:

```js
function myFun(){} 
myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true;}
var myVar=new myFun();
console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // returns 'true' as expected; 
myFun.prototype.anotherFun=function(){return false;}
console.log(myVar.anotherFun()); // now returns 'false' as expected
```

If you want to know more about this subject, check out [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks, that works for me!, but why don't we write function myFun(){this.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true};} instead of function myFun(){} myFun.prototype.anotherFun = function(){return true}; –